# objective-c get json value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have an string with the content below:a

```
 {"friends":[
  {"uid":25,"fbUid":100004063444823,"name":"Andressa Albuquerque","score":100},
   {"uid":51,"fbUid":1297546080,"name":"Daniel Negri","score":5690}
]}
```

So I get the json code as NSArray with the code below:

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSData *friendsData = [friendsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *friendsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:friendsData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];
NSArray *friendsArrayFinal = [friendsArray valueForKey:@"friends"];
```

Until here is everything OK! But now I am trying to get all inner data...
I need to take each "uid", "fbId" and "name" data inside a loop, but I don't know how to do that!

If I use the code below, I see that I am in the right way. But I don't know how to get a "item" property.

```
for(NSDictionary *item in friendsArrayFinal) 
{
   NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}
```

Comment: that isn't an array, by that I mean your root object is a dict, any you have to use valueForKey rather than ObjectForKey because you are mistakenly casting as an array.

Comment: Look at the NSDictionary interface: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

First. Don't use objectForKey,ArrayForKey,BoolForKey or any thing like that. Modern Objective-C syntax provides a simple, readable, key indexing notation. Use that.

It looks like this

```
dict[@"key"];
```

you can of course pass a string variable instead of a literal

```
NSString * key = @"MY_SECRET_SUPER_LONG_KEY_THAT_I_DONT_WANT_TO_TYPE";
dict[key];
```

Second:

If you know they keys you want to access then you should just access them by name

```
for(NSDictionary *friend in friendsArrayFinal) {
  friend[@"uid"]; 
  friend[@"fbUid"];
  friend[@"name"];
  friend[@"score"];
}
```

If you do not know the potential keys or some of them may be missing then you can iterate through the keys

```
for(NSDictionary *friend in friendsArrayFinal) {
  for(NSString * key in friend) {
    NSlog(@"key: %@",key);
    NSlog(@"value: %@",friend[key]);
  }
}
```

Bonus Answer:

If you do `dict[@"keyThatIsNotInDict"]` and the key is not in the dict you will get nil as the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can access values like following

```
for(NSDictionary *item in friendsArrayFinal) {
  NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
  NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForKey:@"uid"]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForKey:@"fbUid"]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForKey:@"name"]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForKey:@"score"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
NSDictionary *results=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:friendsData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
if([[results valueForKey:@"friends"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
         {
             for(int i=0;i<[[results valueForKey:@"friends"] count];i++)
             {
                 [friendsArrayFinal addObject:[[results valueForKey:@"friends"] objectAtIndex:i]];
             }
         }
```

Here you can get all the objects in FriendsArrayfinal. If you want to access specific object than use:

```
 NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friendsArrayFinal objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"uid"]];
```